# Weak compactness

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compactness

Define a map $\varphi \colon [0,1]\to C[0,1]^*$ by $\varphi(x) = \delta_x$. Then $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism for the w*-topology. Let $K$ denote the image of $\varphi$.

I have two questions:

1) Is the set $\overline{\mbox{conv}}^{\|\cdot\|}K$ compact for the weak* topology in $C[0,1]^*$ (in other words, is it weak*-closed)?

2) Is the set $\overline{\mbox{conv}}^{w^*}K$ compact in the weak topology of $C[0,1]^*$ (that is, the weak topology implemented by $C[0,1]^{**}$)?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to apply the theorem of Banach-Alaoglu ? See  in Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem .

Comment: I don't think $\phi$ is a homeomorphism. It is far from being surjective.

Comment: He means homoemorphism onto its image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea for (1).

The weak* closed convex hull of the set of $\delta_x$ is the set of all (Borel) probability measures on $[0,1]$.  So your question is: can any probability measure be approximated in norm by measures with finite support?